# How to open python file in google collab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

How can I open this Python file in Collab "Baseline.ipynb"?
When I go to "open" in the file menu I only find the "adapter.ipynb" and the "utils.ipynb".

[image: I want to open Baseline.ipynb]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Welcome to Collaboratory" screen you posted does not look familiar. Suggestion: Open a new tab with the address https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive ... Navigate from 'MyDrive'  into 'Colab Notebooks' then into the 'Baseline__model_for ... ' folder. With that folder open, right-click on 'Baseline.ipynb' and choose Open with Google Collaboratory.